# how to increase effciency of AWK program

Tags: awk

created a program that checks a csv file against given parameters. however the efficiency went down the drain when I added a character limit using regex

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" }
NF!=17 { print "incorrect   amount    of fields-OFFFENCE FILE"; next}
#splits the line up into 17 seperate fields when encountering a comma,
#however ignores commas located within double quotes and then assigns  each field to a varible to be checked later.
#then counts the amount of  fields if more or less than 17 prints message.
!($1~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,25}")$/) {print "1st field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
#check the data contained within varible 1 that in this case has only  uppercase letters and numbers and consists of
#between 1 and 25 characters and that it also begins and ends with a double quote
!($2~/("[[:digit:]]{1,3}")$/) {print "2nd field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($3~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,8}")$/) {print "3rd field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($4~/^("[A-Z0-9]{0,1}")$/) {print "4th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($5~/^("[A-Z0-9]{0,11}")$/) {print "5th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($6~/^("")$/) {print "6th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($7~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/B) {print "7th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($8~/^("[1-5]{1}")$/) {print "8th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($9~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/) {print "9th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($10~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/) {print "10th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
# the validation above checks for dates in the format #YYYY-MM-DD with either a - or a / as a seperator
!($11~/^("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")|""$/) {print "11th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
#the regex above tests for times to make sure they meet the format of hh:mm:ss
!($12~/^("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")|""$/) {print "12th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($13~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{0,70}")|""$/) {print "13th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($14~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{1}")|""$/) {print "14th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($15~/^("[0-9]{3}")$/) {print "15th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($16~/^(".+{1,2500}")$/) {print "16th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
!($17~/^(".+{1,4000}")|""$/) {print "17th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
{print  "previous field set correct_OFFENCE FILE "}' nppcase_***_******_offence_**************.csv
```

so my question is, is there a way to improve the efficiency.

ps an example is irrelevant its inefficient whether the variable is full or empty basically I want the code to run a hell of a lot faster and the problem is the maximum character length on the regex of $16 and $17 being so high

Comment: Without knowing complete picture of your question/requirement and without seeing complete code it is very hard to help here, kindly add all details in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 here you go full code and basically I just want it to run faster at the moment its taking 5-10 minutes but if I remove the maximum character limit it drops to 20-30 seconds

Comment: IMHO I believe in your previous post too I advised to use `next` at last of any field's failure condition so if any field is INVALID cursor will NOT move further and we may save some checks/cycles. EG--> from `!($1~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,25}")$/) {print "1st field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}` ---> `!($1~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,25}")$/) {print "1st field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";next}`, kindly try once and let me know then?

Comment: didn't work on my end

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. "Here's a hug pile of code, fix it" isn't a great way to get help on this forum. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: `/^(".+{1,2500}")$/` means: a double quote `"` at the start of the line `^` followed by any character `.` repeated 1 or more times `+` repeated 1 to 2500 times `{1,2500}` ending at the end of the line `$`. I suspect you don't want that `+` in there. I'm actually not 100% sure that `{...}` even IS a range expression when the thing preceding it is itself a regexp repetition metachar like `+` - idk what the regexp engine will do with that.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 adding `next`s will only improve the efficiency if there are errors detected. Presumably that doesn't happen in the normal case where there are no errors and efficiency matter plus the OP probably WANTS to detect all errors rather than having to re-run the script after detecting and correcting every error one at a time.

Comment: @EdMorton, yes that's right Ed sir agree with you, I mentioned there in case OP doesn't want to detect all errors and within single error itself OP wants to move cursor to next line. It is difficult to say something without seeing samples to be honest, I had requested OP to add samples too in post same like you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these sorts of changes to all your conditions and you should see a performance improvement due to the simpler regexps:

```
old: !($13~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{0,70}")|""$/)        {print "13th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
new: !( ($13 ~ /^"[A-Za-z0-9]*"$/) && (length($13) <= 72) )

old: !($14~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{1}")|""$/)           {print "14th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
new: !($14 ~ /^"[A-Za-z0-9]?"$/)

old: !($15~/^("[0-9]{3}")$/)                    {print "15th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
new: !($15 ~ /^"[0-9]{3}"$/)

old: !($16~/^(".+{1,2500}")$/)                  {print "16th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
new: !( ($16 ~ /^".+"$/) && (length($16) <= 2502) )

old: !($17~/^(".+{1,4000}")|""$/)               {print "17th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
new: !( ($17 ~ /^".*"$/) && (length($17) <= 4002) )
```

Btw you should be using character classes like `[[:alnum:]]` instead of hard-coding locale-specific ranges like `[A-Za-z0-9]` for portability.

Answer (score 0):

```
!($1~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,25}")$/) {print "1st field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
```

could be replace by something similare (need reviex for each exact regex) like:

```
!($1~/^("[A-Z0-9]+")$/) || (length($1)>27) {print "1st field invalid-OFFENCE FILE";}
```

on my test, it's twice faster because the length only is faster to check the caracter compliant for any possible length inside the string.
Now, optimization depend really of the specification and also asumption we can make on data source.